# Automatically Adding a Number to variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have looked at some sites online and browsed a few answers here and I have had no luck with my question.

I have a PowerShell script to automate account creations using information entered in the host. My question is this, how can I set my script to automatically add a number at the end of the submitted data if it already exists? Code block is below:

```
$Username = Read-host "Enter Desired Username"

#Test

IF(!(Get-ADUser -Identity $Username))
{ Write-Host "$username exists. Adding number.
  HERE IS THE CODE I AM LOOKING FOR TO TAKE THE $Username and automatically add the number at the end.
}
```

If this was already answered, please send me the link and I'll mark this as answered but if not, any suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: `$Username += '5'` but your logic is wrong in your example in the if statement.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with it please?

Comment: what you're doing is `if (user doesn't exist) { tell the user that username is taken! }` when you need to do the opposite: `if (Get-ADUser -Identity $Username) { }`

Answer (score 2):

Since this script isn't being automatically run and there is user input, I would suggest just re-prompting the user if the name is taken:

```
Do
{
    $Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter desired username'
} While (Get-ADUser -Identity $Username)
```

Alternatively:

```
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter desired username'
While (Get-ADUser -Identity $Username)
{
    "Username '$Username' taken!"
    $Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter desired username'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To supplement the other answer, you could also do something like this to determine the next available username:

```
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter desired username'

$TestUsername = $Username

$i = 1

While (Get-ADUser -Identity $TestUsername)
{
    Write-Warning "$TestUsername is taken"
    $TestUsername = $Username + $i++
}

"The next available username is $TestUsername"
```

Within the loop the `++` operator is used to increment the counter variable `$i` and appends that to the original username each time the loop repeats. Note that it is appended first then incremented second, so we start at 1.

Comment: Thank you for the response! That worked great but how can I get it to add the number automatically and prompt what the actual username will be?

Comment: Isn’t that what this does? I’m not sure what you mean sorry.

Comment: What I was hoping for was to have the desired username entered. If it is already takes, the warning stating that it is already in use is displayed. The next available username is displayed, taken into a variable and continues to create the account with the displayed user name.

Comment: So you just create the user using the value of $TestUsername then also output it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I've written such a script. My logic is:

1. Before creating an account, query this account firstly
2. If the account exists, suffix a 2 digits number (from 01, format by `"{0:d2}" -f`
3. Query the suffixed account, repeat step 1 and 2, till the account doesn't exist (use recursive function).

It's the code:

```
$seq = 1
Function Check-Existing {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Account
    )

    while (Get-ADUser $Account){
        $suffix = "{0:d2}" -f $seq
        $Account = $Account + $suffix
        $seq++
        return $Account
    }

    Check-Existing -Account $Account
}
```

(I'll double check the code on Monday)